# How to serialize a single scalar struct with PyArrow?

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, pyarrow

I would like to use a PyArrow scalar struct as key for a RocksDB.
Therefore I need to serialize the scalar as efficient as possible to a bytes array.

I'd imagine something like this:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
key_type = pa.struct([
    ('chrom', pa.string()), 
    ('start', pa.int32()),
    ('end', pa.int32()),
])

value_type = pa.float32()

key1 = pa.scalar(("chr1", 13023, 13035), type=key_type)
value1 = pa.scalar(5.0, type=value_type)

key2 = pa.scalar(("chr4", 10211, 10315), type=key_type)
value2 = pa.scalar(2.0, type=value_type)

# How to implement to_bytes()?
db.set(key1.to_bytes(), value1.to_bytes())
db.set(key2.to_bytes(), value2.to_bytes())

# How to implement from_bytes?
value_test = db.get(key1.to_bytes())
value_test = from_bytes(value_test, type=value_type)
assert value_test == value1
```

As written in the comments, my question is how to implement `to_bytes()` and `from_bytes(bytes_obj, type: pa.DataType)`?

Note that I do not want to encode the schema in `to_bytes()` since the schema is the same across all keys/values and I want to save memory.

Comment: Pyarrow is a columnar format, best suited for batches of data. For serializing single record (like your key), you're better off using something like protobuf.

Comment: Hm OK. I'm already using PyArrow everywhere so I hoped that PyArrow also allows this use case :)

Comment: If you want to use pyarrow, I think currently the only option is to put that scalar in a single column/row RecordBatch, and use the streaming IPC serialization format.